# How to ensure download does not breaks using PHP Curl

Tags: php

I have using PHP's Curl function to download a list of pdfs from the backend. But sometimes some pdfs are corrupted.

I think, this happens because the downloads breaks and it will start to download the next pdf before completing the previous download.

Any idea how to prevent this? I am using the code below:

```
function downloadAndSave($urlS,$pathS)
{
    $fp = fopen($pathS, 'w');    
    $ch = curl_init();
            
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROXY,"http://test:1234");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROXYPORT,1234);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$urlS);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    fclose($fp);    
}
```

I have tried using CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT but no difference. Any other way to prevent this?

Comment: Have you tried `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`?

Comment: @Passerby I used CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, is there a difference?

Comment: @aandroidtest Yes, one is for connecting and the other for the entire transfer. You should try `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`. Also make sure to `set_time_limit(0)` and `ignore_user_abort(true)` as appropriate.

Comment: @aandroidtest Yes, according to [PHP document](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), `CONNECTTIMEOUT` determines the waiting time while connecting to the server, and `TIMEOUT` determines the time `curl` executes.

Comment: Thanks, will include CURLOPT_TIMEOUT and try again.